# Routing to a component that should also route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a component (let's call it "grandfather") that has a router-outlet.

In the "grandfather" component I navigate to another component (let's call it "parent") that also has a router outlet. In the "parent" component I navigate to another component (let's call it "grandson").

Both "parent" and "grandson" receives parameter of ID (the same one).
I would like to know how to configure it and apply the routing to it.

See relevant code:

"grandfather" component:

```html
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

```ts
this.router.navigate(['XXX/Update', id]);
```

"parent" component:

```html
<router-outlet name="BasicView"></router-outlet>
```

```ts
this.router.navigate(['XXX/Update/View',  id]);
```

routing configuration in the module :

```ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'XXX', component: "grandfather"},
 children:[ 
  { path: ':action/:id', component: "parent",
    children:
    [
      {path: 'View/:id', component: "grandson", outlet:'taskBasicView'}
    ] 
  }
 ]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

See the solution:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'XXX', component: "grandfather"},
 children:[ 
  { path: ':action/:id', component: "parent",
    children:
    [
      {path: '', component: "grandson", outlet:'taskBasicView'}
    ] 
  }
 ]
}];
```

And in the "grandfather" component:

```
this.router.navigate(['XXX/Update', id]);
```

There's no need to route in the "parent".